# Access Arg from Previous Function in Composed Function (using Rambda.pipe)

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have a case where I have a pipeline that fits together nicely, but there is an instance where I need to fire off an async call to an API that I don't control. I don't necessarily care about the result, just whether or not it succeeds, and then would like to continue passing along the *arg* to that call (not the return value). So my pipeline looks something like this:

```
const extractUserIdFromResponse = R.andThen( R.prop( user_id ) );
const callExternalApi = tryCatch(
   doApiCall, 
   handleAPIFailure
); 

const pipeline  = R.pipe(
   getRecordFromDatabase, 
   extractUserIdFromResponse, 
   callExternalApi, 
   doSomethingElseWithUserId 
);
```

Basically, I want the `doSomethingElseWithUserId` function to, obviously, accept the `userId` as the arg as opposed to the result returned from `callExternalApi`. I'm a little new to this so I'm unsure if I'm on the right track here or not.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You might want to look at [`R.tap`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#tap), which is designed to run a function for its side-effects but return the input value it received.  It sounds like that is all you need here.  (So you would replace `callExternalApi` with `tap(callExternalApi)` in your pipeline.)  But if you're piping asynchronous calls, you might need to replace `pipe` with `pipeWith(andThen)`.

Comment: Yessss that is what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new to ramda, that's why I'm not sure about the accuracy of the answer, but `doSomethingElseWithUserId` can receive `user_id` from `getRecordFromDatabase` through `callExternalApi`.

**https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-oskar-kzn8d**

```js
import R from "ramda";

const getRecordFromDatabase = () => (
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return resolve({ user_id: 42 });
  })
);

// I assume that you need to pass the arg here in handleAPIFailure as well
const handleAPIFailure = () => {};
const doApiCall = args => (
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return resolve(args);
  })
);

const extractUserIdFromResponse = R.andThen(R.prop("user_id"));
const callExternalApi = R.tryCatch(doApiCall, handleAPIFailure);

const doSomethingElseWithUserId = user_id => {
  console.log(user_id); // 42
};

const pipeline = R.pipe(
  getRecordFromDatabase,
  extractUserIdFromResponse,
  callExternalApi,
  R.andThen(doSomethingElseWithUserId)
);

pipeline();
```

Comment: Hmmm, my issue here though, is that I don't have control over the `doApiCall` function. But, I think you are on to something here... I think I could create a wrapper around the `doApiCall`... something like:

`const wrappedApiCall = async ( userId ) => {
    await callExternalApi( userId ); 
    return userId; 
}`

And then just use the `wrappedApiCall` in my pipeline. And the error would still bubble up and get caught by `handleAPIFailure` just like it would have before.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-ganguly-6zn67 you're right! and you can wrap `await callExternalApi(userId);` with try/catch or `R.tryCatch`